# how to keep the table from looping when get data from API React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `MUIDataTable` to make my table on React JS. I should get data that I want to display on the table from API, but if data in the API is 3 then the table is looping 3 times. I want to only call data once with many lines of data as a response.

Can anyone help me?

here's my code.

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import axios from "axios";


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            errors: null
        };
    }

    getData = async () => {
        const option = {
            url: "API/URL",
            method: 'POST',
            data: { data: .... }
        };
        axios(option)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data.data,
                    isLoading: false,
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            // If we catch any errors connecting, let's update accordingly
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response);
                this.setState({ error, isLoading: false })
            }
            );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, data } = this.state;
        const columns = ["ID", "Name", "Identity"];

        return (
            data.map(post => {
                const { id, name, identity } = post;

                const data = [
                    [
                        [id],
                        [name],
                        [identity]
                    ]
                ];

                const options = {
                    filterType: "dropdown",
                    responsive: "scroll"
                };

                return (
                    <MUIDataTable
                        title={"View Data"}
                        data={data}
                        columns={columns}
                        options={options}
                    />
                );
            })
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
export default App
```

Where's the code I must change to for data loops only and not a table?

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentDidMount()` would run the call every time it mounts, meaning it could re-call the API on subsequent mounts. A quick fix would be to check for state on both the `data` values and perhaps a `waitingResponse=true` flag before making the call.

Comment: should i add that on the state?

Comment: @user13107258 look, it's your project. I'm just a random guy on the internet